# Cast List<Y> to List<X> fast, without new List creation

Tags: c#, list, casting

I need to cast List with references to base type to list with references to derived type. I can't use LINQ ToList, because it creates new list and this is slow for me. Is there in C# some quick cast, maybe like in C++. Thanks.

Comment: [*What have you tried*](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If you just need to iterate the results, then LINQ's `OfType<T>` and `Cast<T>` can be useful.

Comment: If an `IEnumerable<X>` is OK for you: `var ienumerableX = listY.Cast<X>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. And there is a reason for it. Consider the following.

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Cat>();
animals.Add(new Dog());
```

You lose the type safety of the `List<T>` here, this is why `List` is not covariant on `T`. What you can do is cast it to `IEnumerable<X>`, because IEnumerable only supports *getting* an element and this is why `IEnumerable` is covariant on its type parameter.

You don't need to create a new list if you want to just iterate the elements, without changing anything about the list itselft.

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually need a new list? Can you use LINQ [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913.aspx) or [`Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406.aspx)?

```
var baseList = new List<BaseType>();
var derivedItems = baseList.OfType<DerivedType>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast one type to another without creating something new.

Hence, the only option you have is to create a new list, or have something that can iterate over the existing list and acts like a type of another. You could implement your own enumerator, or simply create a method returning a `IEnumerable<TypeY>` and `yield return` inside (which kind of create an enumerator).

```
public IEnumerable<TypeY> Convert(IEnumerable<TypeX> listX)
{
    foreach (TypeX x in listX)
    {
        yield return ConvertXToY(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
List<Y> listY = new List<Y>()
var listX = ListY.Select(y => new X(y));
```

This will create an `IEnumerable<X>` that you can enumerate

Answer (score 2):

LINQ Cast() is going to be you friend here. However, be wary: if you have anything not castable, this code is going to crash.

```
List<object> newList= new List<Object>();
newList.Add("SomeString");
foreach( string s in newList.Cast<string>())
{
    //Do something
}
```